# docker limit disk space utilization

Tags: linux, docker

I want to limit the disk space utilization of a docker container.
I tried using the `docker run -it storage-opt size=` option but it is available only for some disk storage drivers.
I want a solution that works for all drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Run the container in an VM and limit the VM.

Comment: I have a shared hardware system. Many containers on a single VM share the same disk (actual hardware). So I want to each container to limit its disk space utilization. Cannot create a separate VM for each container

Comment: @Akki Add that to your Problem description. I have no idea here.